# Change UI Text Tint Color inside ADAL iOS Auth

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, adal

Inside my app delegate, I've set the global default tint to white because all of the Nav bars inside my app are black. When ADALiOS goes to authenticate a user, I'm brought to this screen pictured below. If you'll look closely, you can see the Cancel button in white letters in the top left corner.

Is there any workaround to change the text color or the navbar color to black?

Inside `viewDidLoad()` I call the following method:

```
    authManager.login() {
            (authenticated: Bool, token: String) -> Void in
            if (authenticated) {
                self.setupMapView()
                self.getJSON()
            } else {
                print("Authentication Failed!")
                self.loginToolbar.alpha = 1.0
                self.listButton.enabled = false
                self.filterButton.enabled = false
                self.refreshButton.enabled = false
            }
        }
```

And here is the `login()` function inside my `AuthManager` class:

```
func login(completionBlock:((Bool, String) -> Void)) {
            var er:ADAuthenticationError? = nil
    let authContext = ADAuthenticationContext(authority: authority, error: &er)
    var token: String!
    authContext.acquireTokenWithResource(resourceURI, clientId: clientID, redirectUri: redirectURI, userId: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")) {
        (result: ADAuthenticationResult!) -> Void in
        if result.status.rawValue != AD_SUCCEEDED.rawValue {
            completionBlock(false, result.error.description)
        } else {
            token = result.accessToken
            let username = result.tokenCacheStoreItem.userInformation.userId
            self.storeUsername(username)
            completionBlock(true, token)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Color of Cancel button in top left corner is white.]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at properties on the AuthenticationContext ADAL gives you, there are some ViewController properties like: parent, child, etc.

The ADAuthenticationContext also allows you to access the .webView property. Perhaps customization is possible through this route.

WebView:

```
_authContext.webView.inputViewController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
```

ParentView

```
_authContext.parentController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
```

I've tried accessing parents NavBar, but I have not seen any success.

I have been tackling this as well this week and can't seem to find a direct solution, however I want to share my findings in hopes it may help you solve it. Perhaps some of these can lead us to accessing the controller's NavBar though which I assume will ultimately be needed to change bar settings like tint/title/color.

Will post further response if I get it working. Please update if you have solved yourself.

UPDATE: I have resolved this on my end by simply adding in my AppDelegate.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackOpaque
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
```

You can probably toggle this in and out of your viewController's Appear/Disappear method's if you need it for only the individual page.

Comment: I have updated my response with an additional solution.